# Does anyone know if the font used by the Yik Yak app is included in CSS font-family?

Tags: css, fonts, social-media

Well the title pretty much says it all. I am looking for the name of the font used by the [Yik Yak app](http://yale.spoonuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/45/2014/11/orange1.jpg) and am also wondering if it can be used on a website by using the font-family class.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions, and programming related questions. This is [not one of those](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is a question to sent a tweet to YikYak over, or use google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yik Yak used AvenirLTStd font. To know better which font they are used, you can 'view source' on your web browser.

I searched on google and you can download it on http://www.cufonfonts.com/en/font/13298/avenir-lt-std

Comment: Ah, I didnt know you could check in the "view source" thing. Thanks.